# PickerView not populating json array

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alamofire, uipickerview

I have a picker view in my view controller, I am trying to populate it with an array loaded from my api using alamofire
when I run the app no data in the pickerview but I see response int the console

the console is returning the response correctly too as arrayValue
the console is returning the response correctly too as arrayValue

no errors too to debug it

[image]

```swift
class AdPostViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    let SiteUrl = "https://xyz.co/apis/sections.php"
    var data = [JSON]()
    var sections = [JSON]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.getSections()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int?
    {
        return sections.count

    }


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerView {
            return sections.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[row].string
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let Secname =  sections[row].string
        print(Secname!)
    }

    func getSections() {

        AF.request(SiteUrl).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print("Validation Successful)")

                if let json = response.data {
                    do{
                        let jsonData = try JSON(data: json)
                        self.data = jsonData.arrayValue
                        print("DATA PARSED: \(jsonData)")
                        for itemDict in self.data {
                            let name = itemDict["name"]
                            self.sections.append(name)
                            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

                            print("Item name: \(self.sections)")
                        }

                    }
                    catch {
                        print("JSON Error", error)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

this is after reloading the pickerView
it loaded the section names separated letters! I mean it made many pickers each has one letter !
[image]

Comment: check for sections[row].string value if it is returning empty string

Comment: You probably nee to add something like `self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` inside `.success` case after you set `self.data` property.

Comment: @gcharita thanks it works, but it loaded the section names separated letters! I mean it made many pickers each has one letter !

Comment: @Jacob if you want only one component then you need to return `1` in `numberOfComponents(in:)` function.

Comment: @gcharita when I changed to 1 it returns nothing !

Comment: @Jacob there are 2 possibilities. Either `sections` array is empty or `name` property not exists in the items of `data` array. (or maybe exists but isn't a `String`)